# XSLT2: How to match a single node based on priority

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to make a new xml structure where only one image-version exist, and that should be the version that is either "a", "16x9s" or "4x3s" - in that priority. So if an image version "a" exist, then only that image is chosen. if it doesn't then look for "16x9s" and finally "4x3s". 
Also needed are a few other nodes(in caps in the wanted result code below), while all the other nodes should be discarded.

**The xml (an excerpt, it can be a lot longer or shorter):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<io>
    <publication id="106125"/>
    <related-images>
        <image id="1112835">
            <caption>null</caption>
            <placement>FRONTPAGETITLE</placement>
            <alignment>left</alignment>
            <photographer></photographer>
            <credit></credit>
            <name>Some text</name>
            <author></author>
            <copyright></copyright>
            <path>Image Root</path>
            <description></description>
            <alt-text></alt-text>
            <image-version version-id="2060510" version-type="16x9s">
                <url>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-1_111283516x9s.jpg</url>
                <width>649</width>
                <height>365</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060512" version-type="a">
                <url>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-16_11128353x4s.jpg</url>
                <width>413</width>
                <height>550</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060513" version-type="4x3s">
                <url>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-16_11128354x3s.jpg</url>
                <width>550</width>
                <height>413</height>
            </image-version>
        </image>
        <image id="1111482">
            <caption>Some text</caption>
            <placement>FRONTPAGELEADTEXT</placement>
            <alignment>left</alignment>
            <photographer></photographer>
            <credit></credit>
            <name>Some text</name>
            <author></author>
            <copyright></copyright>
            <path>Image Root</path>
            <description></description>
            <alt-text></alt-text>
            <image-version version-id="2060099" version-type="4x3s">
                <url>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_11114824x3s.jpg</url>
                <width>640</width>
                <height>363</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060075" version-type="f-tn">
                <url>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_1111482f-tn.jpg</url>
                <width>200</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060094" version-type="y">
                <url>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_1111482y.jpg</url>
                <width>484</width>
                <height>274</height>
            </image-version>
        </image>
        <image id="1111465">
            <caption>Some text</caption>
            <placement>FRONTPAGELEADTEXT</placement>
            <alignment>left</alignment>
            <photographer>Getty Images</photographer>
            <credit></credit>
            <name>Some text</name>
            <author></author>
            <copyright></copyright>
            <path>Image Root</path>
            <description></description>
            <alt-text></alt-text>
            <image-version version-id="2058398" version-type="a">
                <url>/archive/01111/1896_1111465a.jpg</url>
                <width>1499</width>
                <height>1103</height>
            </image-version>
        </image>
    </related-images>
</io>
```

**The wanted result:**

```
<PTR:image>
    <PTR:width>WIDTH OF IMAGE</PTR:width>
    <PTR:height>HEIGHT OF IMAGE</PTR:height>

    <PTR:src>IMAGE URL</PTR:src>

    <PTR:title>
        NAME
    </PTR:title>

    <PTR:description>
        CAPTION
    </PTR:description>

    <PTR:author>
        PHOTOGRAPHER
    </PTR:author>
</PTR:image>
```

I've tried a few things, like xsl:when, but my skill level is not good enough yet to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Cheers.

Comment: Your input snippet has three `image` elements, you result only one. Does that mean you want to extract only one image from all images? Or do you want to extract for each input `image` element the data that matches your conditions?

Comment: Each image node can have multiple image-version nodes in the input xml.
I want to extract only one image url from each image node, and that image url should come from image-versjon a or if a does not exist then 16x9s or if neither of those two exist then 4x3s. If none of the three exist, then no image url should be selected.

Comment: I see now my result code is a bit hard to understand. That result code is what I want for each image node in the input xml. So multiple <PTR:image>nodes, each with only one <PTR:src>, where the source is either from image-version a, 16x9s or 4x3s.
Hope thats clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dr. Kay suggested, create a sequence and use the first occurrence in that sequence.

Here is a complete example.

**XML Input**

```
<io>
    <publication id="106125"/>
    <related-images>
        <image id="1112835">
            <caption>null</caption>
            <placement>FRONTPAGETITLE</placement>
            <alignment>left</alignment>
            <photographer></photographer>
            <credit></credit>
            <name>Some text</name>
            <author></author>
            <copyright></copyright>
            <path>Image Root</path>
            <description></description>
            <alt-text></alt-text>
            <image-version version-id="2060510" version-type="16x9s">
                <url>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-1_111283516x9s.jpg</url>
                <width>649</width>
                <height>365</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060512" version-type="a">
                <url>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-16_11128353x4s.jpg</url>
                <width>413</width>
                <height>550</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060513" version-type="4x3s">
                <url>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-16_11128354x3s.jpg</url>
                <width>550</width>
                <height>413</height>
            </image-version>
        </image>
        <image id="1111482">
            <caption>Some text</caption>
            <placement>FRONTPAGELEADTEXT</placement>
            <alignment>left</alignment>
            <photographer></photographer>
            <credit></credit>
            <name>Some text</name>
            <author></author>
            <copyright></copyright>
            <path>Image Root</path>
            <description></description>
            <alt-text></alt-text>
            <image-version version-id="2060099" version-type="4x3s">
                <url>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_11114824x3s.jpg</url>
                <width>640</width>
                <height>363</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060075" version-type="f-tn">
                <url>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_1111482f-tn.jpg</url>
                <width>200</width>
                <height>113</height>
            </image-version>
            <image-version version-id="2060094" version-type="y">
                <url>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_1111482y.jpg</url>
                <width>484</width>
                <height>274</height>
            </image-version>
        </image>
        <image id="1111465">
            <caption>Some text</caption>
            <placement>FRONTPAGELEADTEXT</placement>
            <alignment>left</alignment>
            <photographer>Getty Images</photographer>
            <credit></credit>
            <name>Some text</name>
            <author></author>
            <copyright></copyright>
            <path>Image Root</path>
            <description></description>
            <alt-text></alt-text>
            <image-version version-id="2058398" version-type="a">
                <url>/archive/01111/1896_1111465a.jpg</url>
                <width>1499</width>
                <height>1103</height>
            </image-version>
        </image>
    </related-images>
</io>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:PTR="whatever the PTR namespace uri is">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="image">
    <xsl:variable name="targetImage" select="
      (image-version[@version-type='a'],
       image-version[@version-type='16x9s'],
       image-version[@version-type='4x3s'])[1]"/>
    <PTR:image>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <PTR:width><xsl:value-of select="$targetImage/width"/></PTR:width>
      <PTR:height><xsl:value-of select="$targetImage/height"/></PTR:height>
      <PTR:src><xsl:value-of select="$targetImage/url"/></PTR:src>
      <PTR:title><xsl:value-of select="name"/></PTR:title>
      <PTR:description><xsl:value-of select="caption"/></PTR:description>
      <PTR:author><xsl:value-of select="photographer"/></PTR:author>
    </PTR:image>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<io>
   <publication id="106125"/>
   <related-images>
      <PTR:image xmlns:PTR="whatever the PTR namespace uri is" id="1112835">
         <PTR:width>413</PTR:width>
         <PTR:height>550</PTR:height>
         <PTR:src>/archive/01112/Thomas-Hicks-16_11128353x4s.jpg</PTR:src>
         <PTR:title>Some text</PTR:title>
         <PTR:description>null</PTR:description>
         <PTR:author/>
      </PTR:image>
      <PTR:image xmlns:PTR="whatever the PTR namespace uri is" id="1111482">
         <PTR:width>640</PTR:width>
         <PTR:height>363</PTR:height>
         <PTR:src>/archive/01111/1904_tugofwar_11114824x3s.jpg</PTR:src>
         <PTR:title>Some text</PTR:title>
         <PTR:description>Some text</PTR:description>
         <PTR:author/>
      </PTR:image>
      <PTR:image xmlns:PTR="whatever the PTR namespace uri is" id="1111465">
         <PTR:width>1499</PTR:width>
         <PTR:height>1103</PTR:height>
         <PTR:src>/archive/01111/1896_1111465a.jpg</PTR:src>
         <PTR:title>Some text</PTR:title>
         <PTR:description>Some text</PTR:description>
         <PTR:author>Getty Images</PTR:author>
      </PTR:image>
   </related-images>
</io>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I did manage to solve it on my own, but I used for-each and choose. Your answer is much better, so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> So if an image version "a" exist, then only that image is chosen. if
>   it doesn't then look for "16x9s" and finally "4x3s".

That's

```
select="(image[@version-type='a'], image[@version-type='16x9s'],
           image[@version-type='4x3s'])[1]"
```

Comment: Thank you :) I accepted Daniel Haley's answer since he provided a complete example, but I appreciate you showing me how to fix my main problem.